# Null ref after switching route in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I have an interesting bug I can't seem to work out and I hope someone with better React knowledge than me can help me work out.

Basically, I have a component (slider carousel, like a Netflix queue) that is trying to set the visibility of two elements (nav slider buttons for left and right nav) if there is overflow of the underlying dev and/or if the underlying div is at a certain position. My visibility setter method is called when onComponentDidMount, when the position of the underlying div changes, and with an window resize event listener.

It works like expected most of the time, however, I have an edge case where I can resize the window, even after going to a new route, and it will work as expected... BUT if I go a new route again I get an error when resizing the window at that point.

It appear as if the refs are not being set after switching routes the second time because they return null.

I've tried detecting if ref is null, but couldn't get that work properly.

```
setCaretVis() {

 const el = this.tray.current;
 console.log(el);

 const parent = this.wrapper.current;
 console.log(parent);

 const posRight = this.offsetRight();
 const posLeft = el.scrollLeft;
 const left = this.caretLeft.current;
 const right = this.caretRight.current;

 const parWidth = el.parentElement.offsetWidth;


 const width = el.scrollWidth;


 if (parWidth >= width) {

   if (!left.classList.contains("invis")) {
     left.classList.add("invis");
   } else if (left.classList.contains("invis")) {

   }
   if (!right.classList.contains("invis")) {
     right.classList.add("invis");
   }
 } else if (parWidth < width) {
   if (left.classList.contains("invis") && posLeft != 0) {
     left.classList.remove("invis");
   } else if (!left.classList.contains("invis") && posLeft === 0) {
     left.classList.add("invis");
   }
   if (right.classList.contains("invis") && posRight != 0) {
     right.classList.remove("invis");
   } else if (!right.classList.contains("invis") && posRight === 0) {
     right.classList.add("invis");
   }
 }


 if (posLeft > 0) {
   left.classList.remove("invis");
  } else {
   left.classList.add("invis");
  }
 if (posRight === 0) {
  console.log("true");
  right.classList.add("invis");
 } else {
  right.classList.remove("invis");
 }
}

offsetRight() {
 const el = this.tray.current;
 //const element = this.refs.tray;

 const parent = this.wrapper.current;
 const parWidth = parent.offsetWidth;

 const width = el.scrollWidth;

 const left = el.scrollLeft;

 let sub = width - parWidth;
 let calc = Math.abs(left - sub);

 return calc;
};

// The componentDidMount method
   componentDidMount() {
   this.setCaretVis();
   window.addEventListener("resize", this.setCaretVis);
   this.setCaretVis();
}
```

I would like to set the visibility (adding/removing a css class) on resize after route change without error.

current error reads: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'offsetWidth' of null

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect that your component is recreated when you go to a new route again, but the old listener is still invoked by the `resize` handler. Try to remove event listener in `componentWillUnmount`:

```
componentDidMount() {
    this.setCaretVis();
    window.addEventListener("resize", this.setCaretVis);
    this.setCaretVis();
}

componentWillUnmount() {
    window.removeEventListener("resize", this.setCaretVis);
}
```

When router recreates the component, it will subscribe to `resize` event again.

From the docs:

> componentWillUnmount() is invoked immediately before a component is unmounted and destroyed. Perform any necessary cleanup in this method, such as invalidating timers, canceling network requests, or cleaning up any DOM elements that were created in componentDidMount

Comment: This was exactly what I needed, and I feel silly because it's so obvious now. Thank you so much for taking the time to think about that!